# ¿Como puedo hacer una instancia de un método Asíncrono en una clase estática?

Tags: android, alertdialog

```
@SuppressLint("ValidFragment")
public static class DialogMensaje extends DialogFragment {
    //se intancian los metodos a utilizar
    ConnectionDetector connect = new ConnectionDetector(getActivity());


    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setTitle("Este es un mensaje");
        builder.setMessage("¿Desea ver el mensaje "+"?")
                .setPositiveButton("Aceptar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        if (conn.isConnectingToInternet()){
//*************************Aquí necesito poner mi metodo asincono*****//
                        } else {
                            //msjError("No tiene conexión a Internet");
                        }
                    }
                }).setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            }
        });
        // Create the AlertDialog object and return it
        return builder.create();
    }
}
```

Comment: Buenos días compañero @Alexis-Caballero, a "instancia de un método Asíncrono" te refieres a que ya tienes uno creado y no sabes como poder llamarlo en ese lugar que indica el comentario del código ?, o también necesitas saber como crear uno ?

Comment: Exactamente compañero, es que he leído que en los métodos estáticos no se puede usar las clases externas sin antes hacer una intancia en ese mismo método estático, y el caso es que necesito que un método asíncrono se ejecute dentro de esa condición

Comment: Según estuve leyendo encontré dos formas en las que podrías llamar a tu método asíncrono. La primera seria haciendo que tu método asíncrono estee en otra clase .java y sea estático lo llamarías así en la linea que necesites:`new MainActivity.MiTareaAsincronaEstatica().execute();` , en esta caso yo llame a un método estatico asíncrono desde mi clase MainActivity en otra clase.

Comment: La otra forma que encontré fue llamando al método de esta forma `new MiTareaAsincrona().execute();` con esto llame a mi método asíncrono normal en el mismo archivo .java donde quiero llamar su método, como vez ambos formas de llamar son iguales en caso de llamar al método asíncrono siendo estático o no

Comment: La segunda forma la intente pero al ser usar el método DialogFragment y al ser estático cuando empiezo a debuggear al ejecutar la acción arroja el error de que el no se puede hacer la instancia ya que es una clase estática

Comment: Ya lo resolví pero gracias por las sugerencias compañero, la forma en que lo resolví fue creando un nuevo método pero sin extender de la clase DialogFragment, use el método AlertDialog sin mas y así ya pude  hacer la instancia de los métodos que necesitaba.